# Windows 10 is showing an OEM Partition with a logical drive letter in Explorer

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-explorer

Recently in Windows Explorer, a "Local Disk (F:)" Drive appeared and shows 34.2MB free of 449MB, but when I double click on it, Explorer shows no files on this drive. I don't have any idea what this is and I haven't plugged in any USB drives lately, and I don't have any plugged in now. I scanned it for viruses and it was okay. Windows also keeps notifying me that this drive is low on disk space.

Does anyone have any idea what this drive is?

EDIT: Looks like this issue is since the April 30, 2018 update to Windows 10, as detailed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-april-update-1804/4f6320de-1eb9-4b06-919c-e19f4fcb178d).

Comment: Have you checked if it is an automounted VHD[X] file?

Comment: @Ramhound In the Disk Manager, I see another partition is the "EFI System Partition" and the F: drive in question is simply "OEM Partition."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue with the April update of Windows 10. With this update, Windows sometimes erroneously assigns a drive letter to one of the normally hidden OEM or recovery partitions and subsequently complains about lack of free space on that partition. The solution is simply to remove that drive letter again.

Sometimes however this is not so easy since the standard Disk Management application refuses to touch the partition. The symptom being that the context menu for the partition in Disk Management shows nothing but "Help". In that case you'll have to run the `diskpart` command line tool from a command prompt with administrator privilege and then use the commands:

```
list volume
select volume <number of offending volume>
remove letter=<offending drive letter>
exit
```

to identify and remove the offending drive letter.